# Indexed rear derailer shifts two cogs for each step

Tags: derailleur, drivetrain, derailleur-rear

I'm trying to troubleshoot poor shifting issues on a mountain bike that appears to have been built out of the spare parts box…

The current problem is "instability" on the rear derailer – the chain bounces around and is very hard to get to settle into gear. The original setup was a SunRace M40 derailer paired with SunRace twist grip shifters and a Shimano 8-speed cassette. The chain measures closer to 7-speed than 8-speed (0.285" a bit over 7.2 mm).

On the [SunRace website](http://www.sunrace.com/en/products/family/m40) the M40 derailer is described as being 7-speed. So I figured that I might have found the problem (7-speed indexing steps paired with an 8-speed cassette), so I tried fitting an NOS SRAM 5.0 8-speed twist grip shifter (which, according to the instructions that came with them, are Shimano compatible). **However,** after reading @Chris in AK's comments below, and failing to find any definitive marks on the shifter, I actually measured the cable travel using the information I found in [this article on drive train compatibility](http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/) and it looks like the SRAM grip shifters are ESP (1:1) as the cable movement is slightly more than 4 mm / click.

The good news is that the shifting seems to be more stable, the bad news is that it reliably shifts two cogs for each clink (e.g., I move the shifter from the 8 position to the 7 position and the chain moves to the #6 cog).

Any ideas about what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the SRAM grip shift that you purchased.  SRAM makes grift shifters for both their own derailleurs and Shimano's.  The [actuation ratio](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bicycles/Maintenance_and_Repair/Gear-changing_Dimensions) on those shifters is different.  SRAM uses a 1:1 ratio for their high end stuff.  Most of Shimano's is closer to 2:1.  The SunRace website you linked to lists the M40 as 2:1, meaning you'll need a SRAM grip shifter with 2:1 actuation.

Comment: OK, just checked the instructions that came with the shifters. They are [SRAM 5.0 Centera](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-NOS-SRAM-5-0-ESP-SHIFTERS-8-SPEED-GRIPSHIFT-Mountain-MTB-Hybrid-Comfort/161741950185?_trksid=p2047675.c100011.m1850&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140602152332%26meid%3Dc075b8e816344604913c644bef34ebcb%26pid%3D100011%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26sd%3D161663668582) (link is to Ebay, shifters were made in 2000, SRAM no longer features them on their site) and claim to be compatible with SRAM Plasma / Quarz / Neos / Centera & Shimano rear derailers.

Comment: If they are ESP, then they are 1:1 actuation (SRAM's marketing name for it) and they will not work with a 2:1 derailleur.  I would look at the shifter itself and not the possibly mixed up packing from the eBay sale.

Comment: There are no ESP markings on the shifter and I had no luck finding anything on the web that would tell me if the shifter was ESP or not, but I did find [this article on drive train compatibility](http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/), so I measured the cable pull and get very close to 4.0 mm per step – so I think they are ESP.

Comment: An excellent way to determine actuation!  Now at least you know what the problem is.